# One Colorbox for two groups of images

Tags: colorbox

There are two groups of images:

```
<div class="gallery1">
<p><a href="image1.jpg" class="group1" /><img src="small/image1.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
<p><a href="image2.jpg" class="group1" /><img src="small/image3.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
<p><a href="image3.jpg" class="group1" /><img src="small/image3.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
</div>

<div class="gallery2">
<p><a href="image4.jpg" class="group2" /><img src="small/image4.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
<p><a href="image5.jpg" class="group2" /><img src="small/image5.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
<p><a href="image6.jpg" class="group2" /><img src="small/image6.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
</div>
```

- is there a way to start and run a Colorbox for each group at a time, but without adding two Colorbox `<script></script>` groups in `<head></head>`? Like having some variable instead of a set selector jQuery('a.group1').colorbox({rel:'group1'});?

**UPDATE 1**:

I have found how it is to use a variable class name:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a").click(function(){
        var myclassname = $(this).attr('class');
        alert('a.'+myclassname);
        jQuery('a.'+myclassname).colorbox({rel:'myclassname'});
    });
    });
</script>
```

But still the question is not solved. Since the script functions like this:

- A newly loaded page: a group of images ("A" tag in them) is clicked on - Colorbox starts up and shows in series all images of the respective group. As it is supposed to.
- But if you continue on the same page without reloading, clicking another group of images ("A" tag in them), Colorbox starts up and shows in series all images of the respective group **plus** all the images of the previously clicked on group. As it is not desired to.

It seems Colorbox must somehow be removed after each start-up / close porcess. So next starting up would be afresh, as if on a newly loaded page.

How can this be achieved? Or maybe there are any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this?

```
<a href="image1" rel="group1" class="gallery">
 <img src="image1">
</a>
<a href="image2" rel="group1"  class="gallery">
 <img src="image2">
</a>

<a href="image3" rel="group2"  class="gallery">
 <img src="image1">
</a>
<a href="image4" rel="group2"  class="gallery">
 <img src="image2">
</a>

<script>
$(".gallery").colorbox();
</script>
```

pay attention to rel attribute in the a href tags
in this example there gonna be 2 diffrent gallery groups